# Cannot get text from table using docx4j

Tags: java, xml, text, tabular, docx4j

**I'm simply trying to output the data found in tables**, however I have only managed to print out memory locations and other obj info. Here I'm using a tablefinder to locate all of my tables in a word doc then traversing through them. I'm just so unbelievably stuck how to print out the data contained in these tables. Below is an image of the Text.docx I am working with along with a snippet of the code. To be clear I'm not sure if I should accessing a table row (Tr) as this code snippet shows, or the parent Tbl object to print out the text contained within the table. In this case, I just want it to print "I", "Just", "Want"... etc.

[image]

```
    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new File("C:\\Users\\1120248\\Test\\Test.docx"));
    MainDocumentPart documentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();

    TableFinder finder = new TableFinder();
    new TraversalUtil(documentPart.getContent(), finder);

    System.out.println("Found " + finder.tblList.size()  + "tables");

    for (Object o : finder.tblList) {

        Object o2 = XmlUtils.unwrap(o);     

        if (o2 instanceof org.docx4j.wml.Tbl) {

            Tbl tbl = (Tbl)o2;
            Tr t = (Tr)tbl.getContent().get(0);

            System.out.println(t.getContent());
            System.out.println(t.toString());
            System.out.println(XmlUtils.unwrap(t.getContent().get(0)));
        }
    }
```

This is the output produced by this setup:

[javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement@a146b11, javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement@f438904, javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement@4ed5a1b0, javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement@18d003cd, javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement@3135bf25, javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement@22ad1bae]

org.docx4j.wml.Tr@4116f66a

org.docx4j.wml.Tc@59c04bee

Comment: Are you tied to docx4j?

Comment: @RabbitGuy Yes I'm tied

Comment: Tr is table row.  tr.getContent will give you a list of tc (table cells).  Each tc  has in turn, getContent, which in this case contains P (paragraph) objects. In those are R (run) objects, which finally contain text runs.   That's what the OpenXML typically looks like.  You can see it by XmlUtils.marshallToString(tbl).

Comment: @JasonPlutext Thank you so much! So I assume I should take an approach like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755952/how-to-read-word-document-and-get-parts-of-it-with-all-styles-using-docx4j)?

Comment: Similar, but the referenced method DocxUtility.getDocxUtility is not part of docx4j.  You can use getContents instead.

Comment: @JasonPlutext please put your comment as answer so we can upvote. This answer saves lives.

Answer (score 0):

Work for me

```
    TableFinder finder = new TableFinder();
    finder.walkJAXBElements(documentPart.getContent());
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who will be stuck on this question. For visibility, the comment by @JasonPlutext is the answer. Tr - Tc - P - R - Text. Table row, to Table cell to Paragraph and R and then add text.